# ASP.NET Master Page - external stylesheet not working?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I'm doing an assignment that involves making an ASP.NET application, creating a web form master page and then further web forms, among some other things.

I'm trying to style my master page, but for some reason, the styling shows up in my design or split view within visual studio, but when I actually load the page, the styling is no longer there.

Here is my head on my master page where I load in my site.css stylesheet (I just dragged it from my solution explorer to here)

```
<head runat="server">
<title><%: Page.Title %></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, intial scale=1, shrink-to-fit-no" />
<link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPHead" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

some example code from my Site.css stylesheet

```
#header1{
color: green;
font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
}

#test {
color: gold;
}

body {
outline: double thick;
outline-color: black;
background-color: black;
}
```

Some example code from the  section on my Master page:

```
        <main>
        <h2 id="test">Test</h2>

        <div id="content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPBody" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>

    </main>
```

For example just above with my  element, in the design view it is indeed the color gold, but when the page is loaded it reverts to black.

Also here is the entire code from one of my .aspx files if that helps:

```
<%@ Page Title="Isolation Ideas" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TaskThreePointOne.aspx.cs" Inherits="Assignment1._0.Home" %>
```

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="WebDevDB" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Idea] ORDER BY [ideaID]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<div class="card-group offset-4" id="card_group">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <asp:Repeater ID="WebDevRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="WebDevDB">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card" id="card_repeater">
                            <img src='<%# Eval("image") %>' class="card-img-top" alt='<%# Eval("idea") + "_image"%>' />
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title"><%# Eval("idea") %></h5>
                                <p class="card-text"><%# Eval("description") %></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: When you request the page with your browser, open up the developer tools and monitor the Network tab. Do you get an error loading the .css file?

Comment: I don't think so, I get 4 404's which are: bootstrap.js, bootstrap.min.js, bootstrap.bundle.js and popper.js which are my scripts but I don't use them. my Site.css and bootstrap.css both have status 200

Comment: I think I actually see the problem, even though I don't know how to fix it. My Site.css file in chrome dev tools > sources is showing an older version, as in what's in there reflects what I had written in there the other day, but not the changes I made today like in the example of my Site.css in my original post

Comment: Do a control F5 to do a hard refresh on your browser. Browsers often cache content files once successfully loaded. There's ways around it, but for now a control F5 should do the trick.